# enviar un formulario a la consola con php

Tags: php, html

estoy empezando en esto de php y pues quisiera saber si me pueden echar la mano con esto. Tengo este formulario sencillo de 4 campos. Lo que necesito que haga es que al presionar el botón de submit se manden todos los datos al servidor.

```
<form action="comentarios.php" name="comentarios" method="post" >
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">Nombre: </label><input name="nombre" class="form-control border border-warning rounded col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" type="text" placeholder="John Doe" pattern="[A-Za-z].{5}">
      <label class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">Correo: </label><input name="correo" type="email" class="form-control border border-warning rounded col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" placeholder="ejemplo@correo.com" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{.5,}">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">Ubicación: </label> <input name="ubicacion" type="text" class="form-control border border-warning rounded col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10" placeholder="Código Postal o Municipio" pattern="[A-Za-z].{3,}">
      <label class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">Comentario: </label><textarea name="Comentario" class="form-control border border-warning rounded col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" placeholder="Introduce tu comentario aquí, lo más detallado posible."></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Enviar</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Limpiar</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php
$nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
$correo = strip_tags($_POST['correo']);
$ubicacion= strip_tags($_POST['ubicacion']);
$comentario = strip_tags($_POST['comentario']);
$_POST['nombre']=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']);
$_POST['correo']=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['correo']);
$_POST['ubicacion']=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ubicacion']);
$_POST['comentario']=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comentario']);
?>
```

En teoria con el strip_tags evito inclusiones de php y html en los formularios, y con el mysql_real_escape_string, se evitan las inyecciones de mysql... Y pues no sé si así se están mandando los campos o no, y como los puedo mostrar en consola.

Comment: Lo primero es que al hacer el envío no podrás verlos en consola, tendrías que hacer un echo en php para pintar lo que llegue y visualizarlos en el network, así te aseguras si te están llegando

Comment: Para utilizar ```mysql_real_escape_string()``` necesitas una conexión a una base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes mandarlos directamente a consola, ni la del navegador por que php se ejecuta en el servidor, ni la del servidor por correr en otra sesión; pero para fines de depuración puedes mandarlos al log del servidor web con `error_log(print_r($_POST,true));`. La ubicación del archivo depende de la configuración del servidor web y la configuración predeterminada de php para el sistema operativo. Deberás observar los valores de configuración de PHP `log_errors` y `error_log` ya sea desde php.ini ó con las funciones `ini_get()` y `ini_set()`.

Answer (score 0):

PAra saber si están llegando los parámetros de POST puedes usar var_dump, tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola José si te refieres a la consola del navegador (console.log()), desde el server no es lo suyo, pero si lo tienes que hacer por narices haz esto:
En tu PHP --> echo("console.log(CONTENIDO QUE TU QUIERAS)");
En tu JS --> eval(RESPUESTA DEL SERVER);